# manipulating websocket values

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, binance

I'm trying to handling websockets with python for the first time.

I created two clients and I want to do some calculate with these two results.
(which is realtime crypto price)

Is it possible to add or multiply numbers of theses result?

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

async def upbit_ws_client():
    uri = "wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        subscribe_fmt = [
            {"ticket": "test"},
            {
                "type": "ticker",
                "codes": ["KRW-BTC"],
                "isOnlyRealtime": True
            },
            {"format": "SIMPLE"}
        ]
        subscribe_data = json.dumps(subscribe_fmt)
        await websocket.send(subscribe_data)

        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            data = json.loads(data)
            print(data['cd'], data['hp'])


async def binance_ws_client():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ts = bm.symbol_book_ticker_socket("BTCUSDT")

    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            print(res['b'], res['a'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    my_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[upbit_ws_client(), binance_ws_client()]))
    my_loop.close()
```

Comment: can you provide an example of a calculation you would like to make?

Comment: Your question is more about using lists and operators rather than websocket. First, I recommend you familiarise yourself with manipulating python lists using this tutorial for example https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp Secondly, you should learn about python operators which you can use to make calculations. Here is another tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the result of above code is printing dict(the json return of request) on my console.
And I want to add or multiply of numbers in this dict. 

what I'm wondering is it possible to add two numbers of websocket result

Answer (score 0):

The results are strings so you need to convert them to floats first in order to have a [data type](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp) which you can calculate:

```
a = float(res['a'])
b = float(res['b'])
```

Then you can substract `a` and `b`:

```
result = a - b
print(result)
```

which you can add to your code like below:

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

async def upbit_ws_client():
    uri = "wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        subscribe_fmt = [
            {"ticket": "test"},
            {
                "type": "ticker",
                "codes": ["KRW-BTC"],
                "isOnlyRealtime": True
            },
            {"format": "SIMPLE"}
        ]
        subscribe_data = json.dumps(subscribe_fmt)
        await websocket.send(subscribe_data)

        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            data = json.loads(data)
            print(data['cd'], data['hp'])


async def binance_ws_client():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ts = bm.symbol_book_ticker_socket("BTCUSDT")

    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            print(res['b'], res['a'])
            
            a = float(res['a'])
            b = float(res['b'])
            result = a - b
            print(result)            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    my_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[upbit_ws_client(), binance_ws_client()]))
    my_loop.close()
```